# Inheritance code returns no value

Tags: java, inheritance

I created a super class called `Employee`, with a subclass called `ProductionWorker` and a driver called `ProductionWorkerDriver`. The program takes my entered info and returns the String values from the Employee class, but not the double and int values from the `ProductionWorker` class. The program I'm using said I had to initialize the values of those as 0, and I'm thinking that's why they show up as zero when compiled. However, the program won't compile without that, so I'm not sure what to do.

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private String employeeNumber;
    private String hireDate;

    public Employee(String n, String num, String date) {
        name = n;
        employeeNumber = num;
        hireDate = date;
    }

    public Employee() {
        name = "";
        employeeNumber = "";
        hireDate = "";
    }

    public void setName(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    public void setEmployeeNumber(String e) {
        employeeNumber = e;
    }

    public void setHireDate(String h) {
        hireDate = h;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;

    }

    public String getEmployeeNumber() {
        return employeeNumber;
    }

    public String getHireDate() {
        return hireDate;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String str = "Employee Name: " + name
                + "\nEmployee #: " + employeeNumber
                + "\nHire Date: " + hireDate;

        return str;

    }
} //end of Employee class


//beginning of ProductionWorker class
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class ProductionWorker extends Employee {
    private int shift;
    private double payRate;
    public int DAY_SHIFT = 1;
    public int NIGHT_SHIFT = 2;

    public ProductionWorker(String n, String num, String date, int sh, double rate) {
        super(n, num, date);
        shift = sh;
        payRate = rate;

    }

    public ProductionWorker() {

    }

    public void setShift(int s) {
        shift = s;
    }

    public void setPayRate(double p) {
        payRate = p;
    }

    public int getShift() {
        return shift;
    }

    public double getPayRate() {
        return payRate;
    }

    public String toString() {
        DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

        String str = super.toString() + "\nShift: " + shift
                + "\nPay Rate: $" + dollar.format(payRate);

        return str;
    }
}//end of ProductionWorker class


//beginning of ProductionWorkerDriver
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProductionWorkerDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name = null;
        String employeeNumber = null;
        String hireDate = null;
        int shift = 0;
        double payRate = 0;
        int DAY_SHIFT = 1;
        int NIGHT_SHIFT = 2;

        Employee info = new Employee(name, employeeNumber, hireDate);

        System.out.println("Employee Name:");
        name = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Employee #:");
        employeeNumber = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Hire Date:");
        hireDate = keyboard.nextLine();

        ProductionWorker info2 = new ProductionWorker(name, employeeNumber, hireDate, shift, payRate);

        System.out.println("Shift 1 or 2:");
        shift = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Pay Rate:");
        payRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(info2.toString());

    }

}//end of ProductionWorkerDriver
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything with the data you've entered:

```
System.out.println("Shift 1 or 2:");
shift = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.println("Pay Rate:");
payRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

... the `shift` and `payRate` variables aren't used again. Changing the values of these *local* variables doesn't change the values in the instance that you created earlier using the same variables.

You should either be calling:

```
info2.setShift(shift);
info2.setPayRate(payRate);
```

... or better, wait until *after* you've asked those questions before you construct the instance. You're also not using your `info` variable at all. Your entire `main` method can be improved to:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Employee Name:");
String name = keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.println("Employee #:");
String employeeNumber = keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.println("Hire Date:");
String hireDate = keyboard.nextLine();

System.out.println("Shift 1 or 2:");
int shift = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.println("Pay Rate:");
double payRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

ProductionWorker worker = 
    new ProductionWorker(name, employeeNumber, hireDate, shift, payRate);

System.out.println(worker);
```

Notice how in each case we don't declare a variable until we need it.

Note that the fact that your employee number and your hire date are both `String` values is a bit of a worry, and it's a bad idea to use `double` for currency values - get into the habit of using `BigDecimal`, or use an integer to represent a number of cents/pennies/whatever.

Comment: Moving the ProductionWorker worker = new... down below the println's seemed to work. Also, the data types for all the variables were set by the textbook I'm using. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user2970463: In that case you should be slightly concerned about your text book - unless it mentions that this is just for simplicity's sake to start with.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
System.out.println("Shift 1 or 2:");
shift = keyboard.nextInt();

System.out.println("Pay Rate:");
payRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

Will update the `shift` and `payRate` of your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //...
    int shift = 0;
    double payRate = 0;
```

Because you're outputting the values from the `ProductionWorker`, and those values are never updated, it will always output 0. Simply because you initialize `ProductionWorker` with those variables does not mean that the reference `shift` in the main method will point to the same place in memory as the reference `shift` inside ProductionWorker.

Comment: There's no `this.shift` in the main method - they're local variables in a static method. `this` is only relevant from an *instance* method, and `this.shift` would be an *instance* variable in that case. Misusing terminology is only going to confuse things further.

Comment: You're right, of course. I assumed those were declared in the class and not the method when I first wrote it, and failed to update it. Updated.